# Turn off nginx authentication for GraphQL api on Gatsby site

Tags: nginx, graphql, gatsby

I've been having a hard time with turning off authentication for the GraphQL api. It keeps failing the build. This is what I have now, which I thought was correct.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

location ^~ /api/ {
   auth_basic off;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;

   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

   # below for some setups on php 7.4
   #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution & Update**

```
location ^~ /api {
    auth_basic off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62180832/12257950

[Turn off nginx authentication for GraphQL api on Gatsby site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137873/turn-off-nginx-authentication-for-graphql-api-on-gatsby-site/62139422#comment109973343_62139422)

---

I have tried to replicate the issue on my end but working properly.

I use OpenResty and added a header `X-reached` with `more_set_headers` (you can use `add_header` alternatively) in the `/api/` location block.

1. You can try with the same and see if the request actually reached the correct location block.

This is my Nginx configuration

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    auth_basic "restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conf.d/.htpasswd;
}

location ^~ /api/ {
    auth_basic off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    more_set_headers 'X-reached true';
}

location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

You can check the header in the response with following command

```sh
 curl -XGET -IL https://site-name.tld/api/path
```

or you can use Network tab in the browser's Inspect.

2.Check that some redirection is not happening.

Comment: Thank you!! Turns out all i need to change was ```^~ /api/``` to ```^~ /api``` and add the one line you posted ```try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Devarshi, this is what worked:

```
location ^~ /api {
    auth_basic off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```